# Doppler/synthesis effect in Android?

Tags: android, soundpool, sound-synthesis

In Android, the `SoundPool.play` API allows for playing sound effects. I'm wondering how I should alter the parameters to achieve a doppler effect:

```
public final int  play (
    int soundID,
    float leftVolume,
    float rightVolume,
    int priority,
    int loop,
    float rate)
```

Comment: You'll probably not be able to do anything like this with the SoundPool. You'll probably have to compute and write the raw PCM data yourself with an [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doppler frequency shift formula is: `f = f0 * (c + vr) / (c + vs)`, where vs/vr -- speed of sender and receiver, and c is the speed of the sound (300m/s for air), you may use `(c+vr)/(c+vs)` as your `rate` parameter in `play()`.

Here's additional info on [Doppler shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect), if you need it.